# Does GPS Navigator send data to Satellite?

Tags: gps, satellite, navigation

Does GPS Navigator send data to satellite?

Is this true about regular devises available in the market?

Comment: Can you describe, in detail, what your concerns are and the specific type of devices you are referring to?

Comment: This could be question at the protocol level, why should it be tied to a specific device? i.e. Does GPS protocol consist of bidirectional communication? or it is only designed for one way receiving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GPS receivers do not transmit any information they are built for receiving information.  The encompassing device then uses said information depending on what the device was built for.

You would be hard pressed to find a 'regular device' on the market which transmits data back to 'the satellites'.  'Talking' to 'the satellites' is not a necessary part of GPS functionality.

As was mentioned in the comments, the devices in question can relay information that has been captured if there is a method to do so on board.  For example, smartphones and other tablets have the ability to communicate over 3/4G and WiFi.  In most instances, however, you must authorize the device to send this information due to privacy laws.

Comment: A somewhat more nuanced answer - no, they don't send any information *to the satellites*, and even if they did, the satellites aren't listening. On the other hand, GPSs embedded in smart phones can (and do) send their positions to the phone network and to various applications which may report the position to a web service or other leaky source.

Comment: @Llaves Yes, but it is not the *GPS receiver* that is transmitting the data.  It's called a receiver for a reason.

Comment: but the OP did ask about GPS *devices*.

Comment: Point taken, my bad.